# Importing a MS-Project mpp file into C# .Net Framework and exporting the data into an SQLite database using MPXJ

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-project, mpxj

**

### Hello

** 
I'm creating a scheduling app that takes in 2 MS-Project .mpp files (master and updated) and converts the data into SQLite tables then compares them both and displays the results and allows you to write the changes you make back to the master file. I had issues with Microsoft Interop because I don't own Microsoft Project. Is MPXJ a viable solution? The documentation I've read on it doesn't have many examples. If so how would I read it in and read it back? Were using MS-project 2016

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of MPXJ, so sorry if I overlook a more straightforward answer. It sounds to me like another way of looking at your problem is you want to:
 1. Parse a MS Project file (and then do it again) and store results in memory
 2. Do some data manipulation and calculations of the in-memory project data
 3. Put that data into a database

I think you're stuck at step 1 because without MS Project, you lack a parser; correct? There are other ways to parse a project file. The simplest may be to have your users first convert the files to a more open format (e.g. XML) when they save them from their instances of MS Project. Lacking that, there are certainly libraries out there that can parse a Project file. Try taking a look at Gantt Project, https://sourceforge.net/projects/ganttproject/ . Being open source, you could look at that parser as a starting point; I'm not a license expert, but you may even be able to re-use the code from there.

Good luck!